# Does not work loop while in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, while-loop, do-while

I have logs in redmine, about users, that have connected from ip of my server. I can do this via command:

`tail -n 100000 /usr/share/redmine/log/production.log | grep -A 3 "192.168.110.50" | grep "Current user" | awk '{print $3}' | head -n 1 | tail -n 1`

I need to write this parameter in variable.

No problem:

`temp=$(tail -n 100000 /usr/share/redmine/log/production.log | grep -A 3 "192.168.110.50" | grep "Current user" | awk '{print $3}' | head -n 1 | tail -n 1)`

It works. But it can return user name `anonymous`. To return other user name i should write `head -n 2`. If it still `anonymous`, i can change in my formula to `head -n 3`.

So ... of course i can do this work

```
#!/bin/bash
temp=$(tail -n 100000 /usr/share/redmine/log/production.log | grep -A 3 "192.168.110.50" | grep "Current user" | awk '{print $3}' | head -n 1 | tail -n 1)

if [[ $temp == "anonymous" ]]; then
temp=$(tail -n 100000 /usr/share/redmine/log/production.log | grep -A 3 "192.168.110.50" | grep "Current user" | awk '{print $3}' | head -n 2 | tail -n 1)
fi
```

But it will work for one iteration. I tried to:

```
while [ $tmp != "anonymous" ]; do
temp=$(tail -n 100000 /usr/share/redmine/log/production.log | grep -A 3 "192.168.110.50" | grep "Current user" | awk '{print $3}' | head -n ((var=var+1)) | tail -n 1)
done
```

But of course it does not work. I can't understand just logically, how can i do this ? Can you help me ? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: could you provide a [mcve] so we can play a bit with the original data and understand the problem better?

Answer (score 2):

The immediate problem is that you're setting the variable `temp`, but checking `tmp`. You also need double-quotes around the variable in case it's blank, a wildcard, or something else troublesome.

But there's an easier way, because `awk` can handle most of the work by itself:

```
tail -n 100000 /usr/share/redmine/log/production.log |
    grep -A 3 "192.168.110.50" |
    awk '/Current user/ {if ($3 != "anonymous") {print $3; exit}}'
```

It'd actually be possible to have `awk` handle looking at the lines after "192.168.110.50" too, but that'd be a little more complicated. BTW, since I don't have any redmine logs (let alone yours) to test with, this has not been properly tested.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `grep -v` :

```
temp=$(tail -n 100000 /usr/share/redmine/log/production.log | grep -A 3 "192.168.110.50" | grep "Current user" | grep -v "anonymous" | awk '{print $3}' | head -n 1 )
```

Note you don't need final `tail -n 1` after `head -n 1`